# Braintree Client token is invalid

Tags: php, ios, braintree

I am able to generate the client token but it says BTClient could not initialize because the provided clientToken was invalid' when i use  on iOS client side

Server side code is in php :-

```
$encodedClientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
echo (  $clientToken = base64_decode($encodedClientToken));
```

Edit 1:-
Here I just want to mimic getting client token (like braintree has done here https://braintree-sample-merchant.herokuapp.com/client_token) from our server
I followed your instruction to create simple server from here https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+php/start/hello-server, and my file generates the client token as well but when i use in my iOS app it give me error that "BTClient could not initialize because the provided clientToken was invalid"

here is my iOS Code

```
NSURL *clientTokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.1:8888/gettoken.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *clientTokenRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:clientTokenURL];
    [clientTokenRequest setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    [NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:clientTokenRequest
     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
         // TODO: Handle errors in [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] and connectionError
         NSString *clientToken = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         // Initialize `Braintree` once per checkout session
         self.braintree = [Braintree braintreeWithClientToken:clientToken];

         // As an example, you may wish to present our Drop-In UI at this point.
         // Continue to the next section to learn more...
     }];
```

Comment: I work at Braintree. You haven't shown us either the full code where you add the client token to the page on the server side, or the code where you use it client side, so there isn't any way for us to see what you're doing wrong. I suggest you [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) and send them some more information.

Comment: Are you `base64_decode`ing the client token? You shouldn't be doing that. What happens if you don't?

Comment: It gives me the same error if i just use echo( $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate());

Comment: I think you'll need to [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/). Please provide them with as much information / code as possible.

Comment: provided but they have not replied ,waiting for there response only